# Selenium Python - Upload image when element seems to be hidden

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, image-uploading, hidden-field

So basically I have problem uploading some photo using Selenium Python 
input element seems to be hidden in the page so the .sendkeys method at still I run into some errors.

this is html code of the input element

```
 <div data-react-class="ImageUploadForm" data-react-props="{}" data-react-cache-id="ImageUploadForm-0">
  <input class="hidden" type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png, image/gif">
  <button class="btn btn-lemonfrog text-lg" type="button">Upload photo</button>
 </div>
```

```
base_path = Path(file).parent
filepath = (basepath / "../core/attachments/clientstackphoto.jpeg").resolve()
hiddenuploaderinput.sendkeys(filepath)
```

right now after running above code I'm getting type error :
value = (PosixPath('........./core/attachments/clientstackphoto.jpeg'),)

```
def keys_to_typing(value):
    """Processes the values that will be typed in the element."""
    typing = []
    for val in value:
        if isinstance(val, Keys):
            typing.append(val)
        elif isinstance(val, int):
            val = str(val)
            for i in range(len(val)):
                typing.append(val[i])
        else:
```

> ```
>           for i in range(len(val)):
> ```
>
> E               TypeError: object of type 'PosixPath' has no len()

../../venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/utils.py:150: TypeError

I expect to upload photo successfully, maybe some js injection will help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your error message, I'm not entirely convinced the error message is caused by the hidden file input. If it were, I would expect an `ElementNotVisibleException`.

However, I do see that the input is hidden, so we should run some JS to reveal the input and perhaps we can rule that out as a potential issue.

Code to show image input

```
fileInput = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']")

# display file input so we can send keys
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", fileInput)
```

Alternatively, you may need to execute script on the `class` attribute instead:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('class', 'visible')", fileInput)
```

Once you execute JS to make the file input visible, you can just `send_keys` to it like any other input:

```
fileInput.send_keys("PATH/TO/FILE/HERE")
```

Comment: Seems like there is also some other error regrading type error:  ```in send_keys {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
E TypeError: object of type 'PosixPath' has no len()
selenium/webdriver/common/utils.py:150: TypeError[100%]```

Comment: I will try to copy relative path to jpg file

Comment: Other than that, thanks for the js script I will be helpful for sure :)